# Achieving alignment of text while sending tables as mail

Tags: java, string, jakarta-mail

I intend to send a tabular data as an email to my outlook ID via java.
My email application uses `javamail` API for the same. I saved the tabular data in a string and sent it. eg.

```
String s = { "APPLE" , "    " , "BALL" , "      " , "CAT" };
String s1 = { "DOG  " , "    " , "EEL " , "      " , "FOG" };
String add = s + "\n" + s1;
```

Now I am sending this composed string as email.  NOTE My string has lot of columns.The text appears to be "OUT OF ALIGNMENT" in the received mail.How do i make the data look tabular ?

Comment: You realize this code does not even compile as Java? You cannot assign a String array literal to a String variable (s, s1).  Please post code that you actually try to run, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You can't tabulate text if the font is proportional (e.g. Times, Arial, etc.). And in plaintext e-mail, you don't control the font. What you can do is to create HTML e-mail, and use the `<TABLE>` tag in that HTML. But this requires sending MIME-formatted mail.

Comment: Thanks. I sent the mail in HTML format. It works